# Adding values of column b when filtering on values of column a

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime

I have a long csv file that has two columns. My first column has an integer representing the date, and the second column has another integer representing temperature. An example of what it looks like is below:

- 20160101  30
- 20160102  32
- 20160103  45
- ...
- 20171231  28

How would I add the values of the second column by filtering on the integer values?

For example, add values 20160131 < x < 20160301 to find sum of all temperatures in February 2016.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Hard to improve it if we can't see it. I'm also missing a concrete question here, looks more like a proclamation of some good intents.

Comment: have you tried anything? what part is blocking you? Reading a CSV file? filtering a list? summing values?

Comment: Are you using numpy or pandas, or are your data in regular Python lists?

Comment: My difficulty is filtering this list. I am able to read the CSV values.

Comment: The date is `row[0]` converted to an `int`

Comment: @P.Hinz can you add the code that reads in the csv values/show what format they're in once you're in the python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but works.

```
import csv

def filter_csv(start_date, end_date, csvfile):
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    total_temp = 0
    for row in spamreader:
        values = row[0].split(',')
        if start_date <= int(values[0]) <= end_date:
            total_temp += int(values[1])
    return total_temp

with open('d.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    total_temp = filter_csv(20160101, 20160102, csvfile)
    print(total_temp)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Olaf! I really appreciate it. I am working on a project of mine and this really helps!

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you : ) If you have any other questions related to python, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `pandas`. You can convert your series to `datetime`, then perform a `groupby` operation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [20160101, 20160102, 20160103, 20171231],
                   'Value': [30, 32, 45, 28]})

# or to read from csv
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['Date', 'Value'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

res = df.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['Value'].sum().dropna()

# Date
# 2016-01-31    107.0
# 2017-12-31     28.0
# Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

You may wish to drop null values for months that are not in scope.

In addition, you may wish to apply `.reset_index()` to return a dataframe instead of a series.